# The command exams2html() does not generate HTML page when it is run from RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-exams

I do not know why `exams2html()` does not produce HTML page when I run the command from RStudio but it is fine when I run from R itself. Both R and RStudio are updated to the latest version. I saw Zeileis et al. (2014) mentioned a similar issue in their paper "Flexible Generation of E-Learning Exams in R...". But it is unclear for me why this happens with the latest version? Does anyone have any idea how to fix that issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine reported a similar behavior recently under Windows 10 using R 4.0.0 and a current RStudio. We could track this down to `browseURL()` not working in the default temporary directory associated with an R session. Maybe you have the same problem.

For him the following worked:

```
library("exams")
exams2html("swisscapital.Rmd", dir = ".")
browseURL("plain1.html")
```

This creates the `plain1.html` output HTML file in the current working directory (`"."`) and then manually opens the file in the browser using `browseURL()`.

By default (without a `dir=` argument), `exams2html()` essentially does the same thing in a dedicated temporary subdirectory in `tempdir()`. On my colleagues machine, essentially all steps worked but `browseURL() couldn't open the HTML file that was successfully created.

If this is also what happens for you, you can try the following:

```
exams2html("swisscapital.Rmd")
```

which should create at least one copy of `plain1.html` in a subdirectory of `tempdir()`:

```
dir(tempdir(), recursive = TRUE)
```

If so, you can try to open that file from within R

```
browseURL(dir(tempdir(), "plain1.html", recursive = TRUE, full = TRUE)[1])
```

or manually. For my colleague, manually opening the file (e.g., via the Windows Explorer) worked but `browseURL()` did not.

Unfortunately, this is as much as I know about the problem up to now... It's possible that this is related to the RStudio browser but we haven't explored this further.

As for the problem described in Zeileis et al. (2014): This was fixed a long time ago by RStudio. Nevertheless you could try to see what happens if you set: `options(browser = NULL)` before running `exams2html()`.

Any other pointers are also welcome.

Comment: Thanks, Achim. browseURL("plain1.html") works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I still don't know why this problem occurs with the files in `tempdir()` though. Can you replicate the problem without `exams2html()`. Does the following work in R vs. RStudio for you? `f <- file.path(tempdir(), "foo.html")` then `writeLines(c("<html>", "<body>", "<p>Hello World!</p>", "</body>", "</html>"), f)` and `browseURL(f)`.

Comment: Yes, it is opening "Hello World!" on the HTML page.

Comment: After loading 'exams' package, I've just added the command-line 'options(device.ask.default = FALSE, browser = NULL)'. I have no longer any issue with 'exams2html()'.

Comment: OK, thanks for the update! Does my "Hello World!" example work both with the default options in the RStudio browser and your modified options?